# Allowing to select only from one group in wpf datagrid row

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

i have a WPF Datagrid which uses grouping. I want to have multiple rows to be selectable, but i want the user only to be able to select from one group. They should not be able to select from different groups at the same time.

If the users select some items from group one, they should be able to right click on the row, a context menu opens with "do something" and a loop should run which executes a function for each item.

This Datagrid has a group style that uses a control template that shows an expander and show in the content of the expander an items presenter.

Could you tell me what i could do? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture the change of selection on one of your `ListCollectionViews` and then deselect the one that was previously selected.  Unfortunately there is no feature at the `DataGrid` level that makes it enforce exclusive selection among the inner `DataGrids`